# Is there any option to filter data by model's filed in django python?

Tags: python, django

I am new to **Django**, Is there any option to display data by choice? I am able to filter by category but I have to filter by choices or model's field. Or is there any option to multiple filters in one template? Or can we filter by using two foreign keys in one model? Here is my Product model where I have used filed (member) for the filter but I could not do that then I have used another model for the filter.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    MEMBER = (
        ('For Kids', 'For Kids'),
        ('For Lover', 'For Lover',),
        ('For Teacher', 'For Teacher'),
        ('For Boss', 'For Boss'),
        )
    category                = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='products', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    member                  = models.CharField(max_length=200,choices = MEMBER)                 
    title                   = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug                    = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    image                   = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/%d/%m/%Y', blank =True)
    description             = models.TextField(blank=True)
    price                   = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    stock                   = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    available               = models.BooleanField(True)
    created                 = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated                 = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering              = ('-title',)
        index_together        =  (('id','slug'),)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**and my category model :**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug        = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True, unique=True)
    image       = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/%d/%m/%Y', blank =True)
    parent      = models.ForeignKey('self',blank=True, null=True ,related_name='children', on_delete=models.PROTECT)

     
    class Meta:
        unique_together                 = ('slug', 'parent',)
        ordering                        = ('title',)
        verbose_name                    = 'category'
        verbose_name_plural              = 'categories'
```

**view.py**

```
def eventmore(request,id,slug):
    products = None
    categories = Category.get_all_categories()
    categoryID = request.GET.get('category')
    if categoryID:
        products = Product.get_all_products_by_categoryid(categoryID)
    else:
        products = Product.get_all_products()

    data = {}
    data['products'] = products
    data['categories'] = categories
    
    
    return render(request, 'events-more.html', data)
```

What can I do to filter by choices(member) or How can I make a nested category or filter data by nested?

Comment: You place multiple questions here, you should try to focus on a single problem and ask a single question in one post.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find all the info you need https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/ and yes you can filter multiple times and/or with multiple arguments.
For example:

```
data_entries = Data.objects.filter(name='max', age=10).filter(email='max@gmail.com')
```

or

```
data_entries = Data.objcets.filter(name='max')
data_entires = data_entries.filter(age=10, email='max@gmail.com')
```

will produce the same result.

In your case just filter it with regular text value:

```
category = Category.objcets.get(pk=pk)
product = Product.objects.filter(member='For Kids', category=category)
```

Comment: Thanks! your given link is helpful.

Comment: No problem :) Feel free to accept my answer if it helped you to solve your problem.

Comment: No, the problem is not solved yet, but now I am trying model manager.